# Make ListView look the same despite Android version

Tags: android, listview, android-theme

My application uses a `android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat` and I'm trying to make the "Overscroll" effect look the same on Pre-lollipop and Lollipop.

On pre-lollipop the Overscroll has the `Holo-blue` color and on Lollipop and above, it uses the colorPrimary attribute.

Most related answers I find on SO are either very complicated (I think this should be a one-liner, preferable in the App theme) or "borks" the default effect on lollipop and looks wierd.

So can can I write to set the overscroll color to colorPrimary on pre-lollipop devices?

My style.xml (App Theme) file currently contains

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_forest</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_soil</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_green</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/my_forest</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
```

I also find it very strange that the `colorControlHighlight` color is not used when selecting items in the ListView on pre-lollipop but the default `holo-orange` color.

Comment: Well, the idea is that the view looks native on the OS version (and so will change its look with version) so that the app does not feel like an alien.

Comment: I think that the existence of Appcompat libraries (Bringing material design to pre-lollipop devices) clashes with that point of view..

Comment: "I think this should be a one-liner, preferable in the App theme".  I would LOVE to agree with this, but its just not the case.  Its more than a few lines occuring in the right spots.

Comment: Okay, maybe one-liner was a bit of an exaggeration. But at least that I could assign a ListView theme that holds the right colors for the right attributes. Unfortunately, finding my way through Styles, themes and support libraries across different versions is still a jungle to me :P

Answer (score 0):

Glow is taken from R.drawable.overscroll_edge, so I guess you won't be able to replace it easily. It would be easier to replace the EdgeEffect class with custom drawable. See:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/EdgeEffect.java#EdgeEffect

So maybe this is what you're looking for:

[image]

Unfortunately this is something really hidden and you won't be able to get that glow without reflection. The above screenshot was taken on Gingerbread, so if you're not afraid of hacks, it's possible. The code is rather long, so I won't paste it here. You can find the implementation in ScrollView and RecyclerView classes of [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon). There's no ListView (it's now replaced by RecyclerView), but you should be able to get that working as well. It's a copy of Lollipop's glow set as edge effect, so it works and looks like it should.

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/RecyclerView.java

Comment: Thanks for your time, but for me, reflection is above the line. Someone else might be interested in this though!